# Databrick adding column with with column in select statement

Tags: sql, databricks-sql

In SQL Server we can create new column by adding some value like below

```
select *, new_column = fixed_value 
from table
```

I want to replicate this in Databricks SQL, but in Databricks I'm getting an error "new_column is not present".

How to do this in Databricks for temp table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in databricks you use aliases, which you also can use in sql server and other rdms

```
 select *,  1 as new_column from table
```

Answer (score 0):

you can always hardcode columns:

```
select 
  *, 
  'john' as name, 
  'us' country, 
  9999 as population 
from  <table_name>
```